# Setup a second wireless AP without ethernet cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

I am on shared wifi in my apartment, probably with multiple routers configured as bridges over the building.

## I have 2 issues:

- All devices are shown all the time, when you want to AirPlay something or just select a speaker (not Bluetooth) you have 30+ smart speakers showing in the list.
- I have a device (Philips Hue Bridge) that can only be connected by ethernet and I have no ethernet plug.

## What am I trying to do:

1. Being able to connect wirelessly to the original wifi network provided in my building
2. Creating new wifi (that I will be the only one to know the password, where I will only see my devices)

## Question:

**How to do this?**

---

> #### If my network knowledge is good:
>
> - The "bridge mode" will not create a new network
> - The "AP mode" needs the router to be connected through ethernet
>
> #### Bonus points:
>
> 1. keeping performance reasonable.
> 2. I do not possess the router yet, so I am looking for the ones that could achieve what I am looking for. (I am currently checking wifi 6
>    ones)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you need a device that acts as both a WiFi client and a WiFi router, assuming you want the devices that connect the latter to have Internet access. I'm not entirely sure if there is / isn't such kind of device on the market, but I suppose in the worst case, you can more or less achieve your goal with a typical WiFi router (actually an AP should do) and an SBC like RPi.

Answer (score 1):

[dd-wrt](https://dd-wrt.com/) is capable of client mode, where it connects to a WiFi AP and shares the connection over ethernet. You can then connect a second router/WAP to the client via ethernet cable and set it up with NAT and firewall to create your own isolated network.

I had a similar configuration running for a few weeks. I occasionally had problems with the client AP not reconnecting after the main AP was down and had to powercycle the client. Apart from that, it was a pretty stable ping and bandwidth connection.

Note that dd-wrt is quite a bit more complicated to configure than the typical consumer-grade router, especially when using non-typical setups like client mode.

Comment: Sounds like you need two extra devices anyway.

Comment: That's an interesting solution! I will consider that if I cannot find any other way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to find the correct answer because I am lacking some basic network knowledge but here it is!

It is indeed possible to connect a router to an original AP through wifi and itself emit another Wifi network, hence separating devices connect to each network but still sharing the same internet access.

## How to do it?

It is by bridge mode! Search if your router is compatible with either wifi extension or bridge mode. If it does it should provide you with a way to either use the same name and SSID or to use different ones: you simply need to choose different ones.

If you are going this way and your router provides you the option of setting different channels: set a different channel than your main router it will make your connection more stable!